# Create and save multiple list of text into Isolated Storage

Tags: list, windows-phone-7, save, isolatedstorage

How do I create more than one list of text data and save it into the isolated storage?
I need to retrieve and display different saved list as well.

I am doing an application like a drink list where user can create multiple drink list containing many different kinds of drink.

I can only create and save one list of drink text at the moment. If I were to add more drink text inside the list again and save it, the list will be overwritten by the latest different drink text.

---

**// Save List of drink text**

```
    private void addListBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        storage.CreateDirectory("ListFolder");

        StreamWriter writeFile = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("ListFolder\\savedList.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, storage));
        for (int i = 0; i < (Application.Current as App).userDrinksList.Count; i++)
        {
            String drink = (Application.Current as App).userDrinksList[i].ToString();
            writeFile.WriteLine(drink.ToString());
        }
        writeFile.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("List added into favourite list.");
     }
```

**// Display saved lists**

```
    private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        StreamReader readFile = null;
        {
            readFile = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("ListFolder\\savedList.txt", FileMode.Open, storage));

            listNumberListBox.Items.Add(readFile.ReadToEnd());
            readFile.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are saving it as savedList.txt. You need to save each list as a separate file. eg list1.txt, list2.txt etc.

Perhaps you also need a list of lists so you know which file = which list.

Comment: Is there any easier way to save multiple list into the isolated storage? How do i go about creating a list of lists as i dont really know how many list the user want. Do I need a for-loop or something? Thanks!

Comment: Create a class called ChildList. This will have a List<String> property to store a drink List. Create a class called MasterList. This will have a List<ChildList> property to store a list of lists. Serialize MasterList to isolated storage.

Answer (score 0):

Your addListBtn_Click method is assuming it can find the list of drinks in a userDrinksList member of your Application instance, however your PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded method doesn't populate that member.

In your PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded method you could do:

```
    using (IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    using(var stream = storage.OpenFile("ListFolder\\savedList.txt", FileMode.Open))
    using(StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        for (string line = readFile.ReadLine(); line != null; line = readFile.ReadLine())
        {
            listNumberListBox.Items.Add(line);
            ((App) Application.Current).userDrinksList.Add(line)
        }
    }
```

The 'usings' ensure that the resources are properly closed/disposed, so you don't need to explicitly close.  You were reading in the complete contents - you need to read it in line by line.